# load model and StopIteration

Tags: r, keras

I´m using keras R, keras_model_sequential, fit_generator and generator_pred. It works well. And I´ve saved the model. But when I use "load_model" and try to use it for "generator_pred" it ends up with this error.

> Error occurred in generator: argument 'length.out' must be of length 1
>   Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     StopIteration:

Actually the only different is that I use the reloaded model, everything else is the same. Does someone know why?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a "training" generator for "predicting".

- A training generator outputs `X` and `Y`. (that means: length 2)
- A predicting generator outputs `X` only (that means: length 1)

If you know how to get elements from a generator in R, you can create another generator that contains the old generator. The new generator gets an element from the old geneartor and outputs only the first element `X`, discarding `Y`.